# Sharepoint group add user of same AD name of different domain

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to add an user in SharePoint group. 
e.g. User AD account "TEST-USER"

but there is a same AD in different domain as well.
e.g. DOMAIN1\TEST-USER
     DOMAIN2\TEST-USER

so when I add DOMAIN1\TEST-USER I am getting the following error

Sorry, something went wrong
The user does not exist or is not unique.

any idea how to overcome

Answer (score 0):

I just added the users using powershell it works!